# How to represent dents on Tube Geometry in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working on a requirement where I need to represent the dents on the pipeline in 3D.
Pipeline I created using THREE.js's tube geometry as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - geometry - Tube</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0px;
                background-color: #ffffff;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="./three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./TrackballControls.js"></script>

        <script>

            var camera, scene, renderer;
            var mesh,cameraControls;
            var clock = new THREE.Clock();

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
                camera.position.set( 0, 0, 1000 );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                var tubepath1 = [{"point" :new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0)},{"point" :new THREE.Vector3(500,0,0)}];
                var actualpoints =[];
                for(var i=0; i<tubepath1.length; i++)
                {               
                  actualpoints.push(tubepath1[i].point);
                }
                var actualextrudePath = new THREE.SplineCurve3(actualpoints);
                actualextrudePath.dynamic = true;


                var actualtube = new THREE.TubeGeometry(actualextrudePath, 60, 60, 30, false, false);
                actualtube.dynamic = true;
                actualtube.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
                actualtube.dynamic = true;

                var actualtubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(actualtube, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
                { color: 0x0ffff0, shading: THREE.FlatShading, side: THREE.DoubleSide, wireframe: false, transparent: false,
                    vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, overdraw: false
                }));
                actualtubeMesh.name = "actualTube";
                actualtubeMesh.dynamic = true;
                actualtubeMesh.needsUpdate = true;
                actualtubeMesh.useQuaternion = true;

                    // CONTROLS
                cameraControls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
                cameraControls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
                cameraControls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
                cameraControls.panSpeed = 0.8;
                cameraControls.noZoom = false;
                cameraControls.noPan = false;
                cameraControls.staticMoving = true;
                cameraControls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;
                cameraControls.target.set(0,0,0);

                scene.add( actualtubeMesh );

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            function animate() {
                window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                render();
            }

            function render() {
                var delta = clock.getDelta();
                cameraControls.update(delta);   
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Now, the problem is how to represents the dents(3D) on the Tube geometry? Any help or pointers are much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,
Pradeep

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Threecsg.js](https://github.com/chandlerprall/ThreeCSG).

You can use sphere to substract what needs to be a dent. This will be fairly easy compared to calculating this by hand.

```
var tubeCSG = new ThreeBSP(actualtubeMesh);
var sphereCSG = new ThreeBSP(spheremesh);
tubeCSG.subtract(sphereCSG)
actualtubeMesh = tubeCSG.toMesh(material);
```

UPDATE:

To see an working example goto: http://jsfiddle.net/BYzdT/8/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Tried what you have mentioned above(jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BYzdT/), but nothing is showing up:(. Could you please give some working example of Tube Geometry and sphere? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for fixing that, I have changed the approach by modifying vertex values of tube geometry itself to get dents instead of CSG.